# Why git pull origin branchA:branchA can't work and pull origin branchA can work?

Tags: git

my git action is below:

git pull origin mybranch1.3.3:mybranch1.3.3  ------> it rejected and tell me mo-fast-forwrd

git pull origin mybranch1.3.3   --------> works well.

and what's the difference? isn't the last "mybranch1.3.3" means my local branch ?

```
springdeiMac:myApp qiushuitian$ git pull origin mybranch1.3.3:mybranch1.3.3
remote: Counting objects: 196, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (94/94), done.
remote: Total 95 (delta 61), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (95/95), done.
From 192.168.1.39:myApp
 ! [rejected]        mybranch1.3.3   -> mybranch1.3.3  (non-fast-forward)
   a1a652f..3fd1572  mybranch1.3.3   -> origin/mybranch1.3.3
springdeiMac:myApp qiushuitian$ git pull origin mybranch1.3.3
From 192.168.1.39:myApp
 * branch            mybranch1.3.3   -> FETCH_HEAD
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is **git pull** syntax

> `git pull [<options>] [<repository> [<refspec…>​]]`

where `options`, `repository` and `refspec` are optional parameters, but you must supply them to git command, as it is recommended otherwise the default behavior would be as mentioned by [GIT Ducumentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull)

> Often people use git pull without giving any parameter. Traditionally, this has been equivalent to saying `git pull origin`

in the first command you have used [Refspec](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec),

so in `git pull origin mybranch1.3.3:mybranch1.3.3` the **LHS** of **:** is your `<src>` and **RHS** to **:** is your `<dst>`. and to ignore this error you can use `+` in your **Refspec**

As **Git** says

> The format of the refspec is an `optional +`, followed by
>   `<src>:<dst>`, where `<src>` is the pattern for references on the
>   remote side and `<dst>` is where those references will be written
>   locally. The `+` tells Git to update the reference even if it isn’t a
>   fast-forward.

And yes in the second command `mybranch1.3.3` is your local branch. This command means to fetch the data from your `origin` and `merge` it to your local `mybranch1.3.3`

Comment: so the difference is :  "git pull origin mybranch1.3.3:mybranch1.3.3" will not automatically merge if it it not fas-forward. and " git pull origin mybranch1.3.3" will. if using "+" fllowing, they are the same.   is it right ?

Comment: no dear both commands will do merge automatically.
Let me tell you one more important thing.
`Pull = Fetch + Merge`
whenever you use `git pull` it will execute both commands `fetch` and `merge`

`git pull origin mybranch1.3.3:mybranch1.3.3` requires `+` in your case to ignore fast forward.

Comment: NOTE: The semantics of both commands are different but you are using them to behave similarly.